# Getting an out of memory error while using Create React App and Plotly.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, plotly

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[972:000001913A837320]    40900 ms: Mark-sweep 2049.2 (2066.3) -> 2047.3 (2059.3) MB, 2062.9 / 0.1 ms  (+ 179.6 ms in 113 steps since start of marking, biggest step 8.9 ms, walltime since start of marking 2512 ms) (average mu = 0.153, current mu = 0.107) [972:000001913A837320]    42835 ms: Mark-sweep 2048.8 (2059.3) -> 2047.7 (2057.8) MB, 1845.1 / 0.0 
ms  (+ 81.8 ms in 23 steps since start of marking, biggest step 9.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 1935 ms) (average mu = 0.084, current mu = 0.004) al

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF68A20B3BD]
Security context: 0x002c4c9808d1 <JSObject>
    1: _append [000002A11D9F9439] [D:\ReactProjects\plotlytest\myplotlysite\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:~99] [pc=0000014BCF9DB744](this=0x03160f6401b1 <Buffer map = 000000A495510339>,0x02ab7a1c78c9 <String[#1]:  >,151182,27,0x02ab7a1c01b9 <null>,0x02ab7a1c04b1 <undefined>,0x02ab7a1c06e9 <false>)
    2: append [000002A11D9F9391] [D:\ReactPro...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6895F5EBF napi_wrap+114095
 2: 00007FF6895A0B46 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+66998
 3: 00007FF6895A1946 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+70582
 4: 00007FF689DB6E4E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF689D9EF21 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
 6: 00007FF689C6B18C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF689C763C0 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF689C72EE4 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
 9: 00007FF689C686E3 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF689C66D54 v8::internal::Heap::AddRetainedMap+2452
11: 00007FF689C8809D v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+61
12: 00007FF6899EE06F v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1295
13: 00007FF68A20B3BD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546637
14: 0000014BCF9DB744
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! myplotlysite@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myplotlysite@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Above is the error I am recieving. I followed a pretty standard set-up, identical to the one listed on this site: https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/blob/master/README.md

I created a react app. When I create a react app and "npm start" the local host it works perfectly fine. This error occurs when I do the next step:

"npm install react-plotly.js plotly.js" after I do this, the local host no longer works and I get this error.

How can I fix this?

By the way, I'm curious, why does this error still exist for so many years? Is plotly not well for react or something?

Comment: step 1: split that command up. Try `npm i react-plotly.js`. If that doesn't work, the problem is `react-plotly` and you know where to now file an issue. If it does, try `npm i plotly.js`. If that also works, then change your description of where/when the error occurs, but most importantly: ask the people who make the tools. They are _the_ authorities when it comes to these libraries, and at worst they'll tell you it's not their problem (and usually, why) so you have better details to put in your post, but they might actually know what's going on because they know their code better than anyone.

Comment: Based on the last line, the issue is when running `npm start` after installing those libraries, and may be coming from something Babel-related. Is your code just a copy-paste of the example from the link you included, and is your new app from a fresh version of create-react-app? Also can you post your Node version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple issues reported regarding this exact problem on the repo issues tracking, like:

1. [JavaScript heap out of memory error with the quickstart Plot example](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/issues/135).
2. [Javascript runs out of memory when making production build](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3604)

In these issues, we clearly see this is a problem with NodeJS <= 10 memory allocation issue and there are several solutions to this:

### Try to upgrade your NodeJS version to latest 12.x version

Node >= 12 increases the heap sizes automatically and it will work. I suggesst you install [Node Version Manager (nvm) for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) which will allow you quickly and easily install and switch through multiple node version.

### Manually increase `max_old_space_size` to React scripts

Increase heap size using `max_old_space_size` by adding this option with a memory size into the `package.json` script:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start",
  "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
  ...
}
```

### Use [Partial bundles](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#partial-bundles)

> ### Partial bundles
>
> Starting in `v1.15.0`, plotly.js also ships with several partial bundles:
>
> - [basic](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#plotlyjs-basic)
> - [cartesian](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#plotlyjs-cartesian)
> - [geo](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#plotlyjs-geo)
> - ...
>
> Starting in `v1.39.0`, each plotly.js partial bundle has a corresponding npm package with no dependencies.
>
> Starting in `v1.50.0`, the minified version of each partial bundle is also published to npm in a separate "dist min" package.
>
> #### plotly.js basic
>
> The basic partial bundle contains trace modules scatter, bar and pie.

You can load the library from `plotly.js-basic-dist` which it's compiled and will consume less memory when bundling:

```
import React from "react";
// import Plot from "react-plotly.js";
import Plotly from "plotly.js-basic-dist";

import createPlotlyComponent from "react-plotly.js/factory";
const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);
```

Comment: Thanks, updating node didn't work. but increasing max size in scripts worked. I am curious though, is there anything wrong with that method? Compared to the other one like the .js-basic-dist. Does one have limited features/performance compared to another?

Comment: With `js-basic-dist` you just load the basic library and you import additional modules as you use them because most likely you aren't using everything that `Plotly` library has and that's why you better isolate what features you're using and just install and use these. For example there are two separate modules for [`plotly.js-basic-dist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly.js-basic-dist) and [`plotly.js-basic-dist-min`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly.js-basic-dist-min) and there is a separate bundle for each module published in NPM.

Comment: Getting `FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`